# Robot Framework Appium Library: Getting ValueError: Element locator with prefix '//*[@class' is not supported with some keywords

Tags: android, xpath, robotframework

This is with Robot Framework running with Appium version 1.5.04 on an Android physical device with the device context set to NATIVE_APP

Steps to reproduce: using an xpath relationship where the element we want (a button) is a child of a View where there are multiple Views entities at the same level

The derived xpath:  xpath= //*[@class='android.widget.Button' and ./parent::*[(./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[contains(@contentDescription,'Sticky')]]]

This xpath is intended to act on a Button that is a child of a View element that contains the name 'Sticky'

What I'm finding is that the following Click Element keyword works fine (both finds and clicks the element)

e.g.:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     5x    3 sec    Click Element   xpath= //*[@class='android.widget.Button' and ./parent::*[(./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[contains(@contentDescription,'Sticky')]]]
```

However,  any of the conditional keywords, e.g.:    (I don't always want to click the element,  just see if its there or not there)

```
Element Should Be Visible   xpath= //*[@class='android.widget.Button' and ./parent::*[(./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[contains(@contentDescription,'Sticky')]]]
```

(same xpath used)

Gives an error:   `ValueError: Element locator with prefix '//*[@class' is not supported`

I've tried other element values (e.g. ContentDescription) with the same result.   This particular element unfortunately does not have an assigned id.

Is there different xpath syntax that I should be using or a different keyword that would be better suited?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why there is a discrepancy between the two, but I'm guessing the fix is to use `:` rather than `=` to separate the prefix from the locator:

```
Element Should Be Visible   xpath://*[@class='android.widget.Button'...
```

Both robot and the selenium library use `=` to help identify a keyword argument (robot) or locator prefix (selenium). That problem can be avoided by using `:` for the prefix.